# DocuSign - Custom Fields without Recipients

Tags: docusignapi

How to create custom fields that have no link to recipients? Would it be prefill tools? the only option I found but it asks for recipientId and when I give a Get we don't have this information.

Comment: are you trying to add metadata to the envelope? or are you trying to change the documents? 
in other words - do you wan these fields to be visible to the signers?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are trying to do:

- If you are trying to add metadata to the envelope, but not change the way to documents look (meaning, the data is not imprinted on the documents for recipients to see), then you can use [envelope custom fields](https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&rsc_301=&bundleId=pik1583277475390&topicId=qor1583277385137.html&_LANG=enus). Those could be set via the web app or via API.
- If, on the other hand, you want something to be visible to recipients, meaning, you want a change to the way to documents look and you don't want that to be associated with a recipient, then you need [pre-fill fields](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/tabs/prefilled-tabs/). These can also be set via API, see this [blog post](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/common-api-tasks-customize-your-envelopes-pre-fill-fields).